# How to check connection string in SSMS2012?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2012

I'm connected to database. I use db by Management Studio 2012 Express. Can I check connection string by click something in Management Studio?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Within SSMS, I'm not sure there's an easy way to do that.  But a simple query will return you the information (without the password of a connection string, obviously):

```
select
    'data source=' + @@servername +
    ';initial catalog=' + db_name() +
    case type_desc
        when 'WINDOWS_LOGIN' 
            then ';trusted_connection=true'
        else
            ';user id=' + suser_name()
    end
from sys.server_principals
where name = suser_name()
```

Note, `db_name()` will return the current database name if there is no parameter specified, so that is dependent on your current scope.

Comment: just for info: in SSMS 2010, the view sys.server_principals doesn't exist yet. But we can use the table syslogin (if I recall correctly)

Comment: I am new to SSMS. I created a new query with above code and ran it. It says "query executed successfully" but where would I find actual the results? Output window only shows "app exited with error code 0".